# Rename a file with native Ansible functions

Tags: ansible

I need to identify a set of files in a directory and rename all those with a .repo extension.
Is it possible to do it with native Ansible functions? If it's not possible I'll use a pure and hard shell command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to this answer ansible does not support move / rename functionality: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162996/how-to-move-rename-a-file-using-an-ansible-task-on-a-remote-system

If you're careful with fileglob you can workaround not using shell like this:

```
---
- name: copy files to new names and remove old ones
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: copy all .repo files in a spec. directory to new names
      copy:
        src: "{{ item }}"
        dst: whatever_you_want_me_to_be_{{ item }}.reponot
      with_fileglob: "/tmp/repofiles/*repo"

    - name: remove all .repo files in a spec. directory
      file:
        path: "{{ item }}"
        state: absent
      with_fileglob: "/tmp/repofiles/*repo"
```